# books on curvilinear coordinate systems

Tags: calculus, reference-request, book-recommendation, curvilinear-coordinates

I need a textbook that includes curvilinear coordinate systems and explains things rigorously
like cylindrical and spherical coordinates and different kinds of integrations like line integrals surface integrals and so on and also divergence and things like that do u know any book that rigorously explains these subjects? What books do u recommend?
Thank u.

Comment: If you wanted a nonrigorous but clear and intuitive explanation, I'd say check out Griffiths's textbook on electromagnetism. For vector calculus, the intuition is wonderfully clear, and you can imagine how the results were discovered, but providing rigorous definitions and proofs is not as easy as one might hope. For a rigorous development that is still trying hard to be clear, you might check out Hubbard and Hubbard.

Comment: G.M. Fikhtengol'ts "The Fundamentals of Mathematical Analysis". Volume 2, IIRC.

Comment: George Arfken: "Mathematical Methods for Physicists" might be a good choice.  I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank u so much, guys!